# Chef-Server connection with AWS private instances/EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, chef-infra

can I connect AWS private instances to my Locally installed chef-server (**on my local Network**) ? If yes then how? if not then what would be possible solution in order to connect AWS EC2 as well as private instances to chef-server?

Comment: Use VPC Peering and the connect to EC2 instance via Private IP

Comment: Define "locally installed"? Do you mean you installed Chef Server on your workstation?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a VPC and private instances inside a VPC you have several options.

1. Software VPN
2. Hardware VPN
3. Direct Connect.

The fastest to get setup would be a software vpn like [open vpn access server](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00MI40CAE?qid=1513878770498&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title). If you have network devices that can support it you can setup a static or dynamic (BGP) VPN between AWS and your network, option 2.

Hardware VPN requirements

> There are two types of VPN connections that you can create:
>   statically-routed VPN connections and dynamically-routed VPN
>   connections. Customer gateway devices supporting statically-routed VPN
>   connections must be able to:
>
> - Establish IKE Security Association using Pre-Shared Keys
> - Establish IPsec Security Associations in Tunnel mode
> - Utilize the AES 128-bit or 256-bit encryption function
> - Utilize the SHA-1 or SHA-2 (256) hashing function
> - Utilize Diffie-Hellman (DH) Perfect Forward Secrecy in "Group 2" mode, or one of the additional DH groups we support
> - Perform packet fragmentation prior to encryption
>
> In addition to the above capabilities, devices supporting
>   dynamically-routed VPN connections must be able to:
>
> - Establish Border Gateway Protocol (BGP) peerings
> - Bind tunnels to logical interfaces (route-based VPN)
> - Utilize IPsec Dead Peer Detection

The lowest latency option is a Direct connect, a private physical connection between your Network and the AWS backbone. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html

https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Amazon_VPC_Connectivity_Options.pdf

https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#C8

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Welcome.html